# Pure Type Parameters and Mixed Type parameter with member

Tags: scala, generics, types, implicits

After watching a youtube video with the title Scala Type Members vs Type Parameters. I wrote the following.

1. Purely Type parameter version works fine

   ```
    trait Joiner[Elem,R] {
        def join(xs: Seq[Elem]): R
    }



   object Program {

     def doJoin[T,R] (xs: T *) (implicit j: Joiner[T,R] ): R = j.join (xs)

     def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {


       implicit val charToStringJoiner = new Joiner[Char,String] {
         override def join(xs: Seq[Char]): String = xs.mkString("+")
       }
       implicit val charToInt = new Joiner[Char,Int] {
         override def join(xs: Seq[Char]): Int = xs.mkString.toInt
       }


       val s:String = doJoin[Char,String]('1','2')
       println(s)
       val n :Int = doJoin[Char,Int]('1','2')
       println(n)

     }

   }
   ```
2. Mixed Type Member & Parameter version -

   ```
      trait Joiner[Elem] {
         type R
         def join(xs: Seq[Elem]): R
       }


       object Program {

        def doJoin[T] (xs: T *) (implicit j: Joiner[T] ): j.R = j.join (xs)

         def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

           implicit val charToStringJoiner = new Joiner[Char] {
             override type R = String
             override def join(xs: Seq[Char]): String = xs.mkString("+")
           }

           implicit val charToInt = new Joiner[Char] {
             override type R = Int
             override def join(xs: Seq[Char]): Int = xs.mkString.toInt
           }

           val s:String = doJoin('1','2') //doesn't work
           println(s)
           val n :Int = doJoin('1','2') //doesn't work
           println(n)

         }

       }
   ```

Version 1 is fine however version 2 doesn't compile. How  can this be fixed while having both implicit in scope? Specifically how can I specify the return type which will help the compiler resolve the correct implicit

Comment: I don't think it can be done. Under most circumstances the compiler can only disambiguate on the first parameter list.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have two implicit val with the same types Joiner[Char] in the scope.
Split them to different function and it should work:

```
object Program {

  def doJoin[T] (xs: T *) (implicit j: Joiner[T] ): j.R = j.join (xs)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    def do1: Unit ={
      implicit val charToStringJoiner = new Joiner[Char] {
        override type R = String
        override def join(xs: Seq[Char]): String = xs.mkString("+")
      }
      val s:String = doJoin('1','2') //doesn't work
      println(s)
    }

    def do2: Unit ={
      implicit val charToInt = new Joiner[Char] {
        override type R = Int
        override def join(xs: Seq[Char]): Int = xs.mkString.toInt
      }
      val n :Int = doJoin('1','2') //doesn't work
      println(n)
    }

    do1
    do2


  }

}
```

Comment: Yes. with one implicit in scope,  it is fine. With two implicit candiates, it breaks down while the purely parameter type works regardless since I can specify both type. So question is how to make the mixed version work noting that I can't specify return type explicitly to help the compiler resolve the implicit.

Answer (score 0):

How about this. You can specify your return type and the input type is taken from argument.

```
import scala.language.reflectiveCalls

trait Joiner[T, R] {
  def join(xs: Seq[T]): R
}

def doJoin[R] = new {
    def apply[T](xs: T*)(implicit j: Joiner[T, R]): R = j.join(xs)
}

implicit val charToStringJoiner = new Joiner[Char, String] {
  override def join(xs: Seq[Char]): String = xs.mkString("+")
}

implicit val charToInt = new Joiner[Char, Int] {
  override def join(xs: Seq[Char]): Int = xs.mkString.toInt
}

implicit val addJoiner = new Joiner[Int, Int] {
  override def join(xs: Seq[Int]): Int = xs.sum
}

println(doJoin[String]('1', '2'))
println(doJoin[Int]('1', '2'))
println(doJoin[Int](1, 2))
```